# SVR model keeps running forever when trying to fit this on sparse csr matrix

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe with text column , to fit a model on this I convert the text using TFIDF Vectorizer, once that is done I have a Sparse CSR Matrix as output of shape - (1353655, 318304), when I try to fir a support vector regressor model on this , the code keeps running forever

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr_model = SVR(C=0.1).fit(X_train,y_train)
print(svr_model.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Any idea what could be going wrong , is the volume to much to be handled?

Comment: *the code keeps running forever*  so how much time you waited?

Comment: it must have run for 90 mins+ before I killed the process

Comment: 90 mins is not forever and depending on data and Machine, ML models take hours to run (even days in some cases). So wait for few ours before you kill the process

Comment: Obviously ML models can take hours/days to run , not sure if that adds anything to question here. It would depend on the complexity and volume of data that the runtime can go up. Just looking at the model that I am fitting and the data volume does not seem that it should take that long. I am looking for ways to make it faster if possible